# How to replicate Windows 7 Calculators Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

I would like to know how it is possible to replicate the text box used in windows 7, that is when you press a symbol it adds the numbers on the upper part of the text box. I tried adding a label in the text box but it still did not replicate the same effect. Can anyone please give me a hint to what I can try to achieve the same result.

Thanks

Comment: you could probably use graphics object of a winforms control (maybe a panel?), but that is just a free thought

Comment: This task would be much easier using WPF

Answer (score 0):

Use two textboxes and apply events to mathematical operator buttons. (and a graphic underneath if you feel fancy)

I don't think there is a control that can be just 'added', you could alternatively create your own, using a User Control template.